# cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 outputs videos with initial frame superimposed

Tags: python, opencv

How can I output the the video with initial frame superimposed using `cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap  = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()    
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480), isColor = False)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        cv2.imshow('original', frame)
        cv2.imshow('fg', fgmask)
        out.write(fgmask)
        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Next time, please take your time to [format the question properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @Miki sorry I'm a newbie but I'll take care now onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cv2.addWeighted](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html#gsc.tab=0) function to achieve the superimpose effect

however, note that the MOG background subtractor continuously updates it's "idea" of background as new frames are added via the apply function (which is why it eventually removes objects that were originally in the fg mask, but has been stationary for too long), hence the superimposed "initial frame" may be misleading to yourself.

You might be better off superimposing the immediate previous frame / frames instead of the initial frame if you want to see the effect of the fg mask